# Render next components when scrolling

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, next.js13

I have a page that shows many components at one, the components fetch data so it makes the page pretty slow to load.

I would like to show only the first 2 components, and when scrolling to the bottom show `<Hotels />` and then when scrolling to the bottom of Hotels, show `<Nightlife />` and so on.

This is my page now:

```
'use client';

import { IPageProps } from '@/app/[city]/[lang]/page';
import React from 'react';
import ToVisit from './categories/ToVisit';
import Tops from './categories/Tops';
import Restaurants from './categories/Restaurants';
import Hotels from './categories/Hotels';
import Nightlife from './categories/Nightlife';
import Shopping from './categories/Shopping';
import Activities from './categories/Activities';

function CategoryPlaces({ params }: IPageProps) {
  return (
    <>
      <Tops params={params} />
      <Restaurants params={params} />
      <Hotels params={params} />
      <Nightlife params={params} />
      <Shopping params={params} />
      <Activities params={params} />
      <ToVisit params={params} />
    </>
  );
}

export default CategoryPlaces;
```

How can I do that in React?